# "the night held other purposes than our own..." - what is meant by "our own" when referring to purposes of the night related to people?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

I am sorry for the possibly unclear title, I could not find a better one.

I understand the sentence below:

> Into the little room, however, in that moment there came between us
> this uncomfortable sense that the night held other purposes than our
> own— and that my companion was aware of them.

However, I do not get the part about the purposes of the night being different than theirs - because there was no purpose, the people are just sitting in a room. So while I understand the night held other (maybe we could say higher or fated purpose), I cannot see what "our own" could refer to.

Comment: You haven't said, but I expect the context is some horror story involving ***supernatural*** forces (ghosts?, vampires?). And the imagery of "the night" having "purposes, plans" simply *conflates* "the night" with those ghosts (or perhaps just personified "Fate") who are "active" at that time. All it really means is ***There were other [invisible] things going on / plans being carried out*** (in addition to whatever the narrator and his companion were openly planning, between themselves).

Comment: Perhaps unbeknown to the narrator and his companion, they're actually just ***simulacra*** (computer simulation of real people), where from the perspective of whoever programmed the simulation, the "purpose" in putting these two in a room together is to study what they say and do. And ***perhaps*** the writer's companion suspects this to be the case, but has never brought it up in conversation. Just a thought.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Sorry, you are right, it is a ghost story by Algernon Blackwood.

Comment: Actually, to answer your question doesn't require us to know anything about who or what has those ***other*** purposes - ***our own*** simply refers to ***our** purpose / reason for being there.* Presumably you've been reading the book, so you should already know why the writer and companion are in the room, (and what they hope to achieve over the course of the night). In a context where it seems that someone / something else intends to ***thwart*** them.